# localStorage with Jquery Mobile works only 1 time on a new Android system

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, local-storage

I am using the localstorage option to set a variable for using it in another page.The platform is Android
Just to simulate the problem, i just created 2 simple JQM pages and set the variable in page 1 and use it in page 2. That works fine for the first time. When i'm going back to page 1 and set a new value for the variable, page 2 tells me that it is the previous value(!). I'm a little bit lost how to use it. Can someone give me a clue how to manage this? The weird thing is that on an old Android version (like 2.3.3) it works fine, but on a new one (like > 4) it fails. I think it has something to do with ready() event?

Page 1 - Main page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#Klant_Lijst').delegate('li', 'click', function () { var x = $(this).data('nummer'); localStorage.setItem("Nummer", x);});
});
```

Page 2 - sub page

```
$(document).ready(function () {
GetFustInfoKlant(localStorage.getItem('Nummer'));
});
```

I hope someone can give me an hint in a direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please dont use ready() method, use JQM page events like pageshow, pagecreate, pagebeforeshow, etc..

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tried all options, but without success. I changed it now to store the variables into a database. That works on all versions.